# AWS default Access Policy SNS topics and SQS q's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In an attempt to further tighten the security of our solution we are now looking at the used SNS topics and SQS queues. All our components live in the same AWS account.

For starters we want to restrict the access to the SQS queues based on IP. So only requests coming from our NAT Gateway IP will be allowed. We don't allow anonymous access to our SQS queues.

But there seems no way to achieve this as the creator of the SQS queues - the AWS account id - has access per default. So you can't create an effective permission for another user in the same AWS account id. As this newly created user, user2, will fall under the same AWS account id, with the same set of permissions.

Am I correct in my understanding that all users in the same AWS account id have access per default to all created SQS queues as long as their IAM policy permits it?  And is my assumption right that the same behavior goes for the SNS topics?

Below is the policy I would like the implement. Beside this policy I have no other policies active for this SQS q. But it is not honoring the source IP condition. I still can connect from everywhere when I use a correct AWS access key/secret combination. Only when I set the AWS principal to * - everyone - the policy seems effective.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:4564645646464564:madcowtestqueue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid1589365989662",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::4564645646464564:user/user2"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:DeleteMessage",
        "SQS:SendMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:143631359317:madcowtestqueue",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "1.1.1.1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference:

- [Using identity-based policies with Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-using-identity-based-policies.html)
- [Using identity-based policies with Amazon SNS - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-using-identity-based-policies.html)

Comment: Both [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-use-cases.html) and [SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-creating-custom-policies-access-policy-examples.html) support resource-based policies. Thus you are not limited to controlling access only by using identity-based policies. The links provided for sqs also shows how to use sqs resource policy based on IP address.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify your requirements? For example, it is not clear what you mean by "create an effective permission for another user in the same AWS account id".

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon SQS**

Amazon SQS has the ability to define [Amazon SQS policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html). These policies can be used *in addition to* IAM policies to grant access to a queue.

For example, a policy can be added that permits **anonymous** access to a queue, which is useful for external applications to send messages to the queue.

Interestingly, these policies **can also be used to control access to the queue by IP address**.

To test this, I did the following:

- Created an Amazon SQS queue
- Used an Amazon EC2 instance to send a message to the queue -- **Successful**
- Added the following policy to the SQS queue:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Queue1_Policy_UUID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Queue1_AnonymousAccess_AllActions_IPLimit_Deny",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:xxx:queue",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "54.1.2.3/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The IP address is that of my Amazon EC2 instance.

- I then tried send a message to the queue again from the EC2 instance -- **Successful**
- I then ran the identical command from my own computer -- **Not successful**

Therefore, it would appear that the SQS policy can override the permissions granted via IAM.

(Be careful... I added a policy that Denied `sqs:*` on the queue, and I wasn't able to edit the policy or delete the queue! I had to use the root account to delete it.)

**Amazon SNS**

I managed to achieve the same result with Amazon SNS using this **access policy**:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:xxx:topic",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "54.1.2.3/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply. I understand that I can make access policies that contain conditions like the source IP. But this setting only appears to be effective when you set the AWS principal to everyone. I was aiming for a extra security layer by not allowing anonymous access - only a specific AWS account id - plus setting a source IP.

But this seems not doable as I notice whenever I configure a policy with a AWS principal set and a source IP condition it is ignored as it seems the default policy kicks in - all users in AWS account have access. Hence my initial question.

Comment: Could you please confirm the rule set you want to achieve? Please describe it as clearly as possible, because it is not clear what you mean by "only a specific AWS account id", and whether that needs to be _combined_ with an IP address rule or as an _alternative_ to the IP address rule. For example, are you saying "if it comes from this IP address is it always OK, _or_ if it comes from an IAM User with the right permissions it is always OK"? Feel free to update the Question to add these extra details rather than putting it in as a comment.